# Click event inside Iframe

Tags: javascript

inside my **index.ejs** i inserted an **Iframe** Tag to embed another document within the current  document. Inside this Iframe i have a Form.

```
<iframe 
  src="purchase/form.html" scrolling="yes" id="purchase"
  style="min-width:280px;width:100%;height:400px;border:none;"
  frameborder="none" 
  allowTransparency="true" >
</iframe>
```

Inside this Form i want to target a Button with the class of stripe_button and the code looks like this

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg stripe_button" style="z-index: 1;">
      <span class="fa fa-credit-card-alt" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      Pay
</button>
```

Doing this with the following Javascript code

```
// target iframe inside index.ejs
    var iframe = document.getElementById('purchase')
// get iframe content
    var innerDoc = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document;
// targeting class and awaiting click event to run function
    var stripe = innerDoc.getElementsByClassName('stripe_button')
        for (var i = 0; i < stripe.length; i++) {
         var stripe_button = stripe[i]
          stripe_button.addEventListener('click', purchaseClicked)
    }
```

the whole code is inside my ready function

```
if (document.readyState == 'loading') {
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', ready)
} else {
    ready()
```

If i try to run this i get `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)`

and i assume it's because im trying to submit a form on localhost and that makes sense so far also tells me that the click event is working.
But if i delete `type="submit"` from the **button** and refresh nothing happens although the
`purchaseClicked` **function** should get into work.

The `purchaseClicked` function looks like this

```
function purchaseClicked() {
    var priceElement = document.getElementsByClassName('zahl')[0]
    var price = parseFloat(priceElement.innerText.replace('$', '')) * 100
    updateCartTotal()
    stripeHandler.open({
        amount: price
    })
}
```

basically it calls stripe popup payment.

And i know that this works if i would assign the button from within my index.ejs file
for example: `document.getElementsByClassName('checkout_button')[0].addEventListener('click', purchaseClicked)`

I assume it has something to do with the click event.

Same Domain. Im aware of CROSS.

Answer (score 0):

wrapping this function into a entire new function

```
function stripe() {
// target iframe inside index.ejs
    var iframe = document.getElementById('purchase')
// get iframe content
    var innerDoc = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document;
// targeting class and awaiting click event to run function
    var stripe = innerDoc.getElementsByClassName('stripe_button')
        for (var i = 0; i < stripe.length; i++) {
         var stripe_button = stripe[i]
          stripe_button.addEventListener('click', purchaseClicked)
    }
}
```

and calling it inside iframe

```
parent.function()
```

solved it.